# ReactJS API Data Fetching CORS error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors

I've been trying to create a react web app for a few days now for my internship and I've encountered a CORS error. I am using the latest version of reactJS, and placing this in the `create-react-app`, and below is the code for  fetching:

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch('--------------------------------------------',{
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "access-control-allow-origin" : "*",
      "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    }})
  .then(results => results.json())
  .then(info => {
    const results = info.data.map(x => {
      return {
        id: x.id,
        slug: x.slug,
        name: x.name,
        address_1: x.address_1,
        address_2: x.address_2,
        city: x.city,
        state: x.state,
        postal_code: x.postal_code,
        country_code: x.country_code,
        phone_number: x.phone_number,
      }
    })
    this.setState({warehouses: results, lastPage: info.last_page});
  })
  .then(console.log(this.state.warehouses))
 }
```

I'm sorry that I can't post the url for the API due to company rules, however, it is confirmed that there are no CORS setting in the API backend.

However, I encounter the following errors when run on mozilla

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at ------------------. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

and

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at ---------------------------------------------. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
```

If run on chrome it gives the following error

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

and

```
Failed to load --------------------------------------------------------: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

and

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

Another thing is that I am able to open the url in my browsers with no problems or whatsoever.

Please help and thanks!

**Additional Information**

The reason I added the CORS setting is because it gives a CORS error, so removing it does not really solve the issue.

Next I tried to perform proxy setting, however, it now gives

```
Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

According to the internet this is caused becasue the response is not a JSON. However when I checked the API it gives this

[api img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVTJ6.png)

which means that return type should be a JSON right?

**Additional Info**

checking the respond will yield this

{"status":200,"total":1,"per_page":3,"current_page":1,"last_page":1,"next_page_url":null,"prev_page_url":null,"from":1,"to":3,"data":[{"id":1,"slug":"america","name":"america","address_1":"USA Court","address_2":"USA","city":"USA","state":"USA","postal_code":"94545","country_code":"US","phone_number":"10000001","created_by":null,"updated_by":null,"created_at":"2017-11-10 11:30:50+00","updated_at":"2018-06-28 07:27:55+00"}]}

Comment: Have you tried to set a proxy in your `package.json`? Somewhere above your dependencies: `"proxy": "http://yourAPI"`

Comment: do not use **response** headers in a **request** (i.e. `access-control-allow-origin` is a response header) - this will inevitably trigger a CORS preflight, which the server may not understand - but, if the server doesn't allow CORS, there's nothing a client can do about it directly

Comment: *it is confirmed that there are no CORS setting in the API backend* - then CORS won't be allowed - you've answered your own question!!! [read how CORS works here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: If not CORS enabled or api doesn't serve JSONP you have to use a proxy either on server you control or third party service

Comment: it still throws a CORS error even if i removed the cors setting, to begin with it was only placed there after encountering a cors error. I will try the proxy thing first

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The CORS settings need to be setup in the API to allow access from your React app domain. **No CORS settings, no AJAX from different domains**. It's simple as that. You can either add CORS settings to your company API (this is unlikely to happen) or you can work around like described below:

The CORS is solely a mechanism of client browser to protect users from malicious AJAX. So one way to work around this is proxying your AJAX request from your React app to its own web server. As Vincent suggests, the `create-react-app` provides an easy way to do this: in your `package.json` file, simply chuck `"proxy": "http://your-company-api-domain"`. For more details, please see this [link](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#proxying-api-requests-in-development)

Then in your react app you can using relative URL like this: `fetch('/api/endpoints')`. Notice that the relative URL has to match with your company API. This will send a request to your server, then the server will forward the request to your company API and return the response back to your app. Since the request is handled in the server-to-server way not browser-to-server so the CORS check won't happen. Therefore, you can get rid of all unnecessary CORS headers in your request.

Comment: Hello, I added the proxy settings and the CORS error did disappear, but a new error appeared 'Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0'

Comment: @Last that means you bypass the CORS. But the response is not a valid JSON. Notice that the response has "<" as the first character so it's likely in XML format. Could you inspect your response and post it in your questtion?

Comment: Sorry to interrupt, but it is probably the proxy server responding with `404`.

Comment: what happens if the proxy server responds with 404?

Comment: posted the response

Comment: @Last the response you post is actually the wrapper object of the returned data. It's only tell that the request was handled successfully. Could you get and post the content of the response instead? Details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text

Comment: @DatPham sorry i didn't know that still new to react. Updated it

Comment: @Last the response you got was a valid JSON and seem like you got the data from the API. So I don't know what error you got here. Perhaps you can add a `.catch(error => console.log(error))` to your fetch call and debug from there

Comment: @DatPham thanks to you I was able to find the error. After knowing how to look at the response, I knew that there was nothing wrong with the API, so I decided to just remove the mapping and that fixed the problem. I also tried various things and found that CORS error appears when you make a mistake in pulling information that does not exist

Comment: worked! just to be clear after adding proxy in `package.json` you have to remove baseurl from your api, like `/v1/users/` not `https://www.example.com/v1/users/` then only it'll work.

Answer (score 4):

This is what I did using vite

Package.json file add:
"proxy": "http://api_website_where_the_request_is_comming/",

App component or whatever component you making the call do this

let endpoint = `/api/your_endpoint/`;

```
fetch(endpoint).then(function (response) {
    return response.json()
}) 
.then(function (jsonData){
    console.log('Banner log', jsonData);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In your backend, make sure that the app is use cors.

Run this to install cors

```
npm install cors --save
```

Import cors in the app using

```
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors())  // if name of your backend is app
```