# How to bypass CORS error when sending POST request to Google Drive API from react application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, google-api

I am new to web dev & I am having trouble bypassing CORS when I try to send a POST request of a file upload from my React application to my Google Drive account. This is what I am doing in my upload file callback function:

```
function uploadFile(file) {
    var metadata = {
        'name': 'Test File', // Filename at Google Drive
        'mimeType': file.type, // mimeType at Google Drive
    };

    var accessToken = (copied generated access token from OAUTH playground)
    var form = new FormData();
    form.append('metadata', new Blob([JSON.stringify(metadata)], {type: 'application/json'}));
    form.append('file', file);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('post', 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart&fields=id');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onload = () => {
        console.log(xhr.response.id); // Retrieve uploaded file ID.
    };
    xhr.send(form);
}
```

I was following the sample script from https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/bd53b366aedef70e35a35f449c51eced and when I copy the first sample script things seem to be working fine. However, when I upload a file from my desktop, then upload it through my app I receive a 503 error along with:

"... has been blocked by CORS policy. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin ... is therefore not allowed access."

I have been checking some similar questions asked on Stack Overflow and it seems the best approach is to have the server that hosts the resource have CORS enabled. But in this case, I'm requesting from Google's API so what is the best approach to handle this problem? Specifically a client side solution? Any help is appreciated

Comment: If you're using `create-react-app`, you don't have to manually setup web server. React script support a proxy server out of the box, have a look of this answer here for how to config it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51128176/reactjs-api-data-fetching-cors-error/51128913#51128913

Answer (score 1):

use proxy 
https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com

so your URl will be
https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart&fields=id'

concatinate this URL before the Api Url or else send this in headers while calling

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:'*'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, I don't think either way is working because the cors-anywhere proxy basically adds Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '*'  to the response header, but that is still going to throw this error: Cannot use wildcard in Access-Control-Allow-Origin when credentials flag is true and ask you to set the origin in the response to match the request

This is b/c the credentials flag HAS to be true with Google Drive's API. Furthermore, if you use Axios, the proxy doesn't support withCredentials=true