# React app doesn't get API results after deploying to Heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I did basic movie database type app with React and then deployed it to Heroku. App contains input field and it returns results after pressing Enter, and this works just fine locally. My problem is when I deployed my app to Heroku nothing happens anymore when I hit Enter and trying to search something. I belive app works correctly but for some reason it doest't get data from API when app is deployed to Heroku. Any ideas what causing this problem and how to fix this?

[Source code](https://github.com/arttuhar/movieDB)

[Live demo](https://reactmoviedb.herokuapp.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://reactmoviedb.herokuapp.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=bf410ecf&s=dfvdf'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

The error your are getting

[ReactJS API Data Fetching CORS error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51128176/reactjs-api-data-fetching-cors-error)

Comment: So if I change 'http' to 'https' it should fix the problem right?