# ReactJS/Typescript: Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, fetch, cross-origin-read-blocking

I am getting CORB error while trying to fetch using below configuration.
On console it says 'Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response http://localhost:8080/api/xxxxx/xxxxx with MIME type application/json. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.'

```
const {

    token,
    method = RequestMethod.GET,
    headers: customHeaders = {},
    body: requestBody,
    data: requestData,
    credentials = 'omit',
    ...customOptions
  } = options

  const headers: HeadersInit = new Headers({
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    ...customHeaders,
  })
  let body = requestBody

  if (!body && requestData) {
    body = typeof requestData !== 'string' ? JSON.stringify(requestData) : requestData
  }

  if (token) {
    headers.set('Authorization', token)
  }

  const response = await fetch(endpoint, {
    method,
    headers,
    body,
    credentials,
    mode: 'no-cors',
    referrerPolicy: 'origin',
    ...customOptions,
  })
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReactJS API Data Fetching CORS error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51128176/reactjs-api-data-fetching-cors-error)

Comment: My question is related to CORB not CORS, but thank you for taking an effort to help.

Comment: I've never seen a CORB error generated from `fetch`; are you sure that *this* code is responsible for producing that error?

Comment: There are certainly problems with this code (you've said `mode: 'no-cors',` but you try to read the response, and your setting `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` even if you are making a GET request with no request body to describe the type of).