# Issue with CORS policy blocking fetch request from localhost to external API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, cors, fetch-api

Description:
I'm encountering a CORS-related error when making a fetch request from my frontend (running on http://localhost:8080) to an external API (https://mercury-t2.phonepe.com/transact/pg). The error message I'm receiving is:

Access to fetch at 'https://mercury-t2.phonepe.com/transact/pg...token=...' (redirected from 'http://localhost:8080/api/payment/newPayment') from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Additional Information:

Backend is built using Express.js.
Frontend is using React.
Both frontend and backend are running locally during development.
I've verified that the backend endpoint (/api/payment/newPayment) works independently without any CORS issues when tested via tools like Postman.
Request for Assistance:
Could someone help me understand why the CORS policy is blocking my fetch request and suggest potential solutions or additional configurations I might need to implement in order to resolve this issue?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Tried Configuring CORS Headers: I set up CORS headers in my Express backend using the cors package, allowing origins from http://localhost:8080.

- Expected Outcome: Anticipated that allowing the specific

origin in CORS headers would permit requests from the frontend to the external API.
Actual Result: Despite configuring CORS headers, I'm still receiving a CORS policy error when making fetch requests from http://localhost:8080 to the external API. The error persists, blocking the requests.
You can expand upon these points by providing any code snippets or specific configurations you attempted, detailing what you expected to happen and the outcome you observed. This helps the individuals assisting you understand the steps you've already taken and better diagnose the issue.

Comment: `I set up CORS headers in my Express backend` but it's not your API that is causing the CORS errors ... it's `https://mercury-t2.phonepe.com` - do they send CORS headers?

Comment: Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51128913/21957513

Comment: oh, wait *Request header field `access-control-allow-origin`* - but `access-control-allow-origin` isn't a request header - are you putting response headers in your request? You haven't shown your request, but I'm guessing you are putting cors **response** headers into the **request**

Comment: I used frontend and made request to backend const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/payment/newPayment', options);