# How to solve Api response cors error on page refresh in react

Tags: php, reactjs, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

on navigating to watchlist page the pai gives response but on refreshing the page the api gives CORS error

```
`
    useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(myWatchListApi());
  }, [dispatch]);
//
 const config = {
      headers: `Authorization: ${token} `,
    };

    const { data } = await axios.get(
      `https://fxsignals.ae/admin/api/news_api/get_wishlist_by_user/${user_id}`,
      config
    );

`
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReactJS API Data Fetching CORS error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51128176/reactjs-api-data-fetching-cors-error)

Comment: @PRATHEESHPCsometimes it is giving response but when refreshed it gives CORS ERROR

Answer (score 0):

in `config/cors.php`

update `paths` key value like that

```
'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie', 'admin/api/*'],
```

and run again config cache command

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: it a ci3 project and there is no such file in my config folder.any other workaround??

Comment: @RohitRai then you why add laravel tag in this question?

Comment: sorry my bad . could you suggest some other solution